# Encrypting a .NET application

Tags: .net, encryption, obfuscation

I have a .NET project (C#,WPF), and I was wondering if there are any good tools for encrypting this before releasing it to customers. I know a similar question has been asked before ([Encrypting a .NET application and assemblies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494211/encrypting-a-net-application-and-assemblies)), but what I am looking for is someone who has done this on a commercial product.

I have been looking at Assembly Lockbox and CodeVeil, but I do not have any practical experience with either.

It would also be super-nice if any of the tools can be used in the build process on a Hudson server.

Comment: possible duplicate of [encrypting a .Net application and assemblies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/494211/encrypting-a-net-application-and-assemblies)

Answer (score 2):

It is obvious as it was previously answered, that you need an obfuscation tool. Let me help with some of the tools that support integration with build servers:
http://www.secureteam.net/Obfuscator.aspx
http://www.foss.kharkov.ua/g1/projects/eazfuscator/dotnet/Default.aspx
http://www.red-gate.com/products/smartassembly/index.htm
http://xheo.com/products/code-protection
http://www.preemptive.com/products/dotfuscator/overview

Some of them are commercial products, but you definitely need to check them also.
From my experience and previous usage, i had no problems and very satisfying results using RedGate's tool and dotFuscator also.

Comment: This would be in addition to an obfuscation tool. What I am asking is if anyone has used any of the *Encryption* tools for encrypting .NET assemblies.

Answer (score 1):

I have used CodeVeil, it has command-line options for it's programs, and can be included in automated build systems.  I haven't used Hudson, but it works with TeamCity.

Yes, this does encryption, which is different to obfuscation, although it can do that too.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a *.NET Obfuscator*. There are many of them out there, but you have some very specific needs as I read your post :

1. You need a very strong .NET Obfuscator which can handle commercial app:

   - Therefore those apps are kind of big projects, aren't they ?
2. The .NET Obfuscator you are looking for shall be compatible with build-process on some server

[NETGuard.io](https://netguard.io/) is a cloud-based .NET Obfuscator, which means that you can protect your .NET Projct with ease on any plateform you can imagine. It has a strong compatibility module and some very nice feature such as the '*Error Reporter*' one which can be very usefull for commercial applications. It is both strong and safe. I'm using it for my personnal project and for my profesionnal freelancing jobs too.