# DLL encryption without using Obfuscator

Tags: .net, security, dll, encryption

In fact I have been assigned with a task to secure my DLL, so that if I deploy my software to any system no one can modify or read my DLL.
can you please help me how I can encrypt it without using obfuscator?

Comment: Why the requirement to not use an obfuscator?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/494211/encrypting-a-net-application-and-assemblies

Comment: if i use obfuscator, my DLL will work properly??? and what i have read so far there is no way to get your DLL back once it is obfuscated...is it so???

Comment: Encryption doesn't work like this.  The attacker will always have the key,  you want obfuscation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need the software to do this, below are some software you may look into

- Eazfuscator.NET http://www.gapotchenko.com/eazfuscator.net
- dotFuscator http://www.preemptive.com/products/dotfuscator
- fxProtect http://www.maycoms.net/

Please note that obfuscate only make your code harder to read and interpret by human, but doesn't stop people to decompile it.

Answer (score 1):

If you *really* need encryption, you also need:

- A way to store the key securely => dedicated hardware "dongle"
- A complete framework to decrypt the assembly on load or better single methods on call.

Don't do it on your own, buy a solution. I can recommend WIBU CodeMeter, but I'm biased, it's my employer.

Answer (score 0):

Another third party product other than the ones listed above is NetLib Encryptionizer. It can encrypt managed or unmanaged DLLs (not the EXEs though). It uses transparent file encryption rather than obfuscation. That is, it does not modify the DLL except to encrypt it. (Disclaimer: I am from [NetLib Security](https://netlibsecurity.com))